# Using PowerShell to compare 1 file with an entire folder of files

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell script that takes the contents of a csv file, and compares it with the contents of each individual csv file in a folder. The goal here is to stop a system from processing a file if a file that has the same exact contents is already in this particular folder.

At the very basic, I've been able to compare the contents of one file against another with this:

```
$file1 = Get-Content C:\test.csv -raw
$file2 = Get-Content C:\test1.csv -raw
if ($file1 -eq $file2) {
    Write-Host "They are the same"
```

Has anyone been able to accomplish something like this?

Thanks,

Comment: Would comparing file size and or timestamps not be sufficient for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want Get-FileHash.

**Are these two files the same?**

```
$file1 = Get-FileHash -Path C:\test.csv 
$file2 = Get-FileHash -Path C:\test1.csv 
if ($file1.Hash -eq $file2.Hash) {
    Write-Host "They are the same"
```

**Are there any identical files in this directory?**

To operate on the contents of an entire directory--say, a directory of log files--you can get hashes of every file and group them. Identical files will have a count of 2 or more.

```
Get-FileHash -Path '.\*.log' | Group-Object -Property Hash | `
  Where-Object {$_.Count -ge 2} | `
  Foreach-Object { @{$_.Group.Hash = $_.Group.Path} }
```

The `Foreach-Object` and a hash table (shown) makes the output easier to use, I think. You could substitute an array for the hash table with `Foreach-Object { @($_.Group.Hash , $_.Group.Path) }` and get output that's somewhat easier to read, but a little harder to use down a pipeline.

**Are any files in this directory the same as *this* file?**

To answer the question, "Are any files in this directory the same as ThisFile?", first get the hash of ThisFile, then compare its hash to that of the files in the directory.

```
$ThisFile = Get-FileHash -Path 'L:\Logs\ThisFile.log'
Get-FileHash -Path '.\*.log' | Where-Object {$_.Hash -eq $ThisFile.Hash}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, this was what I was looking for. If there's a duplicate file, I just need to figure out how I can make an "if" statement to do something else now.

Comment: Thanks again Mike, I got this to do what I wanted. Very cool! If there's a way I can buy you a coffee let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Compare-Object`:

```
$are_files_equal = -not [bool] (Compare-Object $file1 $file2)
```

Because `Compare-Object` returns the differences between the two csv files, if they are the same, it will return nothing and hence, be cast by `[bool]`
 as `$false`. With the `-not`, then the boolean `$are_files_equal` is  respective True or False to whether the files are equal or not.

You may want to add the `[switch]` type parameter `-CaseSensitive` to `Compare-Object` if you want it to be, since it isn't by default:

```
$are_files_equal = -not [bool] (Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -CaseSensitive)

if ($are_files_equal){
    write-host "They are the same"
} else {
    write-host "They are different"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To me it seems like OP got stuck writing the command to compare each file against each other file. And while the other answers are faster or more concise, an easy way to compare every element of a list with every other element that works in every programming language is with nested loops, like:

```
foreach ($file1 in Get-ChildItem *.csv)
{
    foreach ($file2 in Get-ChildItem *.csv)
    {
        if ($file1.name -ne $file2.name -and (Get-Content $file1 -raw) -eq (Get-Content $file2 -raw))
        {
            Write-Host "$file1 and $file2 are the same"
        }
    }
}
```

As LotPings mentioned, this compares files twice, which could be avoided by adding a test that `$file1.name` is lexicographically ordered before `$file2.name`.

Comment: All these responses look promising, but I'm not able to get something to work. I'm trying to use the nested loop - but it's not working. At the very least - how can I take a file named "test.csv" and compare that contents with the contents of a folder named "CSV" that contain a bunch of other .csv files? Mainly just looking for a yes there's a match or no, there's not.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had time to test my solution. You can try to replace the `*.csv` in the outer loop with `test.csv`, although I also haven't had time to test that. If it doesn't work, try with simpler commands first or type `help about_foreach`, etc., to understand what these commands really do.

Comment: That's the most inefficient method thinkable as it compares the files twice. It's also useless as it doesn't output which files are equal.